# Pricing American Put Options via Binomial Tree in Matlab

Tags: options, matlab, binomial, put, american

I currently am completing a Computational Finance Assignment, and am trying to figure out how to alter this Matlab code which prices a European put or call option, in order to price an American Put Option. I honestly thought it would be as simple as placing a `max()` in the backwards recursion step. I don't want you to just provide the altered code, as I'd rather learn, but I have been thinking about this for a while and am at crossroads. I have left my altered code in thus far in the hope that you could point me in the right direction.

```
function price  = tree_slow(S0, K, T, r, sigma, opttype, Nsteps)
%   
% S0 - current stock price
% K - strike
% T - expiry time
% r - interest rate
% sigma - volatility
% opttype - 0 for a call, otherwise a put
% Nsteps - number of timesteps

%Output
%   price : option price

%Practical 1: compute the timestep size (Delta t) and tree parameters
delt = T/Nsteps;
u = exp(sigma * sqrt(delt) );
d = 1./u;
a = exp( r*delt );
p = (a - d)/(u - d);

%vector of payoff and option price in the tree
W = zeros(Nsteps+1,1);

%Practical 1: compute the S value at time T and store it in W
for j=0:Nsteps
    W(j+1,1) = S0*u^(j)*d^(Nsteps -j);
end

%Practical 1: compute the payoff
if(opttype == 0)
    W = max(W-K,0); 
else
    W = max(K-W,0);
end

%Practical 2: fill in the backward recursion
for n=Nsteps-1:-1:0%timeloop

    %loop over all possible S levels at time t_n 
    for j=0:n 
        %instruction: complete the expectation formula
        W(j+1,1) = max(K-W(j+2,1),exp(-r*delt)*( p*W(j+2,1) + (1-p)*W(j+1,1) ));
    end

end
%instruction: fill in with the right index
price = W(1);
```

Comment: Barring dividends and risk-free interest, American and European puts should have the same value. Putting in a max() would imply you have a "lookback" option which lets you retroactively choose when to exercise the option. The interest rate may make a difference, albeit a small one.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* as simple as just taking the `max()`. The problem is that you took the wrong one.

You must consider the max between the *intrinsic value of the option* on the one hand and its discounted continuation value (which is an expectation in the risk-neutral world) on the other.

In your final loop, you should therefore replace the line

```
W(j+1,1) = max(K-W(j+2,1),exp(-r*delt)*( p*W(j+2,1) + (1-p)*W(j+1,1) ));
```

with

```
W(j+1,1) = max(phi, exp(-r*delt)*( p*W(j+2,1) + (1-p)*W(j+1,1) ));
```

where for the tree node `j` at the time iteration `n`

```
w = (+1) * (opttype == 0) + (-1) * (opttype ~= 0)    % w = (opttype == 0) ? +1 : -1
S = S0*u^(j)*d^(n-j)
phi = w*(S-K)
```